# Extract everything but a regex match

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe where each row contains an e-mail's raw text. I need to clean up the data to extract the following columns: From, To, CC, Subject, and the body of the text. The e-mails typically look like this:

```
From   : Vincent Adultman
To     : Business Person, 
Cc     : 
Subject: On the subject of business Transactions

Dear blabla,

We would like to bla bla to improve our bla bla by X%.


Thanks in advance
```

I was able to extract the first four columns using the following regex expression:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=['text'],dtype='string')

df['from'] = df.loc[:,'text'].str.extract(pat=r'(\bFrom .+)')
df['to'] = df.loc[:,'text'].str.extract(pat=r'(\bTo .+)')
df['cc'] = df.loc[:,'text'].str.extract(pat=r'(\bCc .+)')
df['bcc'] = df.loc[:,'text'].str.extract(pat=r'(\bBcc .+)')
df['subject'] = df.loc[:,'text'].str.extract(pat=r'(\bSubject: .+)')
```

Now I am trying to extract the rest of the body that starts at `Dear blabla`. However since every e-mail is different, I can't go matching on `Dear blabla`.

How can I match all the text except the first four matches I have already done?

Here is what I have tried:

```
df.loc[:,'text'].str.extract(pat=r'^(\bFrom .+|\bTo .+|\bCc .+|Bcc .+|\bSubject .+)')
df.loc[:,'text'].str.extract(pat=r'^[(\bFrom .+|\bTo .+|\bCc .+|Bcc .+|\bSubject .+)]')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You think that `^` negates something. In your case, `^` just matches the start of a string.

Comment: To expand on @WiktorStribiżew answer: You can do negation with a negative lookahead `?!`. There are websites that display what your current regex matches, see https://regex101.com/r/K6GnSb/1/

Comment: Try `df['body'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'^(?:\n?(?:(?:From|To|Cc|Subject)\s*:).*)+\s*', '')`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew that ended up working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['body'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'^(?:\n?(?:From|To|Cc|Subject)\s*:.*)+\s*', '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/roA1SD/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\n?(?:From|To|Cc|Subject)\s*:.*)+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `\n?` - an optional newline, line feed char
  - `(?:From|To|Cc|Subject)` - either `From`, or `To`, `Cc`, `Subject`
  - `\s*:` - 0 or more whitespace chars and a `:` char
  - `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars.